# activeadmin add_new has_many association link in custom form

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

So i have this problem where i want to add some markup in my form besides the basic form in my admin panel and i'm using active admin for that.

below is my basic form code

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :first_name
    f.input :last_name
    f.input :bio
    f.input :description
    f.input :affiliate_link
    f.has_many :videos, :allow_destroy => true do |video|
      video.input :title
      video.input :subtitle
      video.input :description
      video.input :asset, as: :file
      video.input :teaser, as: :file, input_html: {class: 'teaser'}
      video.input :pdf, as: :file
      video.input :categories, collection: Category.where("parent_id is not null")
      video.input :tags, as: :check_boxes, wrapper_html: {class: 'checkbox-margin-left'}
    end
  end
  # f.inputs do
  #   render partial: "shared/templates"
  # end
  f.actions
end
```

now i was trying to render a partial hoping that it would be part of the whole form but in reality the form disappeared and only partial was rendered so i thought i should change my strategy and here's what i did next. i created a form partial.

```
form :partial => "form"
```

it rendered the form and i added my markup in the partial but i got another problem. The has_many association for videos was rendering not as a new record form but as a select option. Now i wanna know how can i make it render a new record form that generates a new form for this association instead of showing me a select box.

Answer (score 0):

They both look like bugs.  Switching to a partial is a good idea and should work.  If you submit issues on GitHub we will look at them.